# holomorphic function $f$ in $\overline{B(0,1)}$ has nonzero derivative at the maximal value point.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f:\overline{B(0,1)}\subset \mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be holomorphic in the closed unit disc $\overline{B(0,1)}$, i.e. there exists holomorphic function $g$ such that $g|_{\overline{B(0,1)}}=f$, if $f$ is not constant, and  there exists $z_0$ such that
$$|f(z_0)|=\max_{z\in \overline{B(0,1)}} |f(z)| $$
then by maximal modulus principle $|z_0|=1$, my problem is if we can prove $f'(z_0)\neq 0$. Any help will be appreciated:)

Comment: @Conrad thank you very much!

Comment: happy to be of help